# Is there any faster way to get the disk space usage instead of using du -sh?

Tags: linux, filesystems, storage, disk

I've around 100 TB of data in the folders which need to be checked. But du -sh is taking more than a day to get the results.
is there any other alternative other than du -sh and ncdu ?

I tried du -sh and it took more than a day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df <DISK_MOUNT_POINT_OR_DEVICE_NAME>`.

Comment: Antonio Petricca
I forgot to add the requirement. I need to find this at the subdirectory level which is on nfs. Not at the root volume level.

Comment: In that case `du` is the only way.